# Getting started with post processing

Tags: post-processing, photography-basics

It's been along time that I have wanted to get started with post processing, but I have a big problem.

I don't know where to start. I have looked around internet and this site too, but I can't figure out how and where to start.

I wonder if someone could introduce a book, course or anything, as the first step to me. Please be specific.

Comment: If you've looked around this site, you should know that product recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Look for books on Amazon and read the reviews. Understanding the LAB colour space is very useful for colour correction.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to get started is just search on [Youtube](http://youtube.com) for "Photoshop", "Lightroom" or just "post-processing photography" and watch a few videos.

Comment: Stack Exchange generally discourages link only answers - we *strongly* prefer answers to be self contained.